# Material UI issue with InputAdornments

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this issue where when I have my form autocomplete from Chrome or Firefox it seems that the InputAdornment I have on does not get styled in the same blue and just looks really off.

[image]

here is my code snippet where I bring in the InputAdornment and not sure what I should change to have this display properly and not throw that ugly white space on the icon.

```
  <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <TextField
            name='lastName'
            variant='outlined'
            required
            fullWidth
            value={lastName}
            onChange={onChange}
            InputProps={{
              startAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position='start'>
                  <AccountCircle />
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
            }}
            label='Last Name'
          />
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add style directly in the InputProps the issue seems to be fix.

```
<TextField
  name='lastName'
  variant='outlined'
  required
  fullWidth
  value=""

  InputProps={{
   
    startAdornment: (
      <InputAdornment position='start'>
        <AccountCircle />
      </InputAdornment>
    ),
    style:{backgroundColor:"#E8F0FE"},
  }
}
  label='Last Name'
/>
```

here a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-wu-m2u91?file=/src/form.js:189-480) working example